# Android studio - RatingBar setOnTouchListener not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ontouchlistener, ratingbar

I am trying to setup a `scrollView` where inside I have a `Grid layout` with few `rating bars` in it. When I click/touch on these the avarege value is sent to a final `Rating Bar` which is outside to the `scrollView`.

Everything is working however, each `ratingbar` need to be clicked/touched two times in order to send its value.

Any Idea why is this happening? If I move the `grid layout` outside from the `scrollView` the `rating bars` work as expected(on one click/touch)

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGPtR.png)

the Code I am using to send the value from rating bar is:

```
    Valutazione[0].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    onClickRate1();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            Valutazione[1].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    onClickRate1();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            Valutazione[2].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    onClickRate1();
                    return false;
                }
            });

....

public void onClickRate1()
    {

        RatingBar Valutazione[] =
                {(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1), (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2),
                        (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar3), (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar4),
                        (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar5), (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar6),
                        (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar7), (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar8),
                        (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar9), (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar10)
                };
        RatingBar rateTot =(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBartot);

        float Valore[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10};
        Valore[0]=0;Valore[1]=0;
        Valore[2]=0;Valore[3]=0;
        Valore[4]=0;Valore[5]=0;
        Valore[6]=0;Valore[7]=0;
        Valore[8]=0;Valore[9]=0;
        Valore[10]=0;

        int j=0, divisore=0;

        TextView finalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textrate);


        while(j<=9) {

            Valore[j] = Valutazione[j].getRating();

            if(Valore[j] > 0) divisore++;

            j++;
        }

        Valore[10] = ( Valore[0] +  Valore[1] +  Valore[2] +  Valore[3] +  Valore[4] +  Valore[5] +  Valore[6] + Valore[7] +  Valore[8] + Valore[9]) / divisore;


        totalRating(rateTot, Valore[10], finalResult);

    }



    private void totalRating(RatingBar totalBar, float valoreTotale, TextView totalText) {

        totalBar.setRating(valoreTotale);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `setOnTouchListener` use `setOnRatingBarChangeListener`.

1) import android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener;

then:

```
Valutazione[0].setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

                onClickRate1();
            }

        });
```